# How to get SMS log on Lollipop

Tags: android, logging, crash, sms

How do I get the SMS log from Lollipop? I can get the log from Kitkat and lower API without problems (See code below). But with Lollipop, the app crashed (See LogCat).

Can anyone help?

LogCat:

```
11-10 13:11:01.734 32120 32120 E AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
11-10 13:11:01.734 32120 32120 E AndroidRuntime: Process: de.sr.mobilestats, PID: 32120
11-10 13:11:01.734 32120 32120 E AndroidRuntime: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'boolean java.lang.String.contains(java.lang.CharSequence)' on a null object reference
11-10 13:11:01.734 32120 32120 E AndroidRuntime:    at de.sr.mobilestats.SMS.getSMSData(SMS.java:161)
11-10 13:11:01.734 32120 32120 E AndroidRuntime:    at de.sr.mobilestats.SMS.onCreateView(SMS.java:87)
11-10 13:11:01.734 32120 32120 E AndroidRuntime:    at android.app.Fragment.performCreateView(Fragment.java:2053)
11-10 13:11:01.734 32120 32120 E AndroidRuntime:    at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:894)
11-10 13:11:01.734 32120 32120 E AndroidRuntime:    at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1067)
11-10 13:11:01.734 32120 32120 E AndroidRuntime:    at android.app.BackStackRecord.run(BackStackRecord.java:833)
11-10 13:11:01.734 32120 32120 E AndroidRuntime:    at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:1452)
11-10 13:11:01.734 32120 32120 E AndroidRuntime:    at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl$1.run(FragmentManager.java:447)
11-10 13:11:01.734 32120 32120 E AndroidRuntime:    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
11-10 13:11:01.734 32120 32120 E AndroidRuntime:    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
11-10 13:11:01.734 32120 32120 E AndroidRuntime:    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
11-10 13:11:01.734 32120 32120 E AndroidRuntime:    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5221)
11-10 13:11:01.734 32120 32120 E AndroidRuntime:    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
11-10 13:11:01.734 32120 32120 E AndroidRuntime:    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
11-10 13:11:01.734 32120 32120 E AndroidRuntime:    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:899)
11-10 13:11:01.734 32120 32120 E AndroidRuntime:    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:694)
11-10 13:11:01.791   814  1428 W ActivityManager:   Force finishing activity de.sr.mobilestats/.MyActivity
11-10 13:11:02.305   814   878 W ActivityManager: Activity pause timeout for ActivityRecord{1af2b04b u0 de.sr.mobilestats/.MyActivity t743 f}
```

And here is the codes:

```
private void getSMSData() {
    Uri uri = Uri.parse("content://sms");
    Cursor managedCursor = getActivity().getBaseContext().getContentResolver().query(uri, null, null, null, null);    
    int number = managedCursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow("address");
    int type = managedCursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow("type");
    int date = managedCursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow("date");
    olnum.clear();
    oltype.clear();
    oldate.clear();
    ilnum.clear();
    iltype.clear();
    ildate.clear();
    dlnum.clear();
    dltype.clear();
    dldate.clear();
    countin = 0;
    countout = 0;
    countdel = 0;
    while (managedCursor.moveToNext()) {
        phoneNumber = managedCursor.getString(number);
        smsType = managedCursor.getString(type);
        smsDate = managedCursor.getString(date);
        smsDateTime = new Date(Long.valueOf(smsDate));
        formate = new SimpleDateFormat("MMM-yyyy");
        sdate = formate.format(smsDateTime);
        sdate = sdate.replace(".", "");
        String cType = null;
        int cTypeCode = Integer.parseInt(smsType);
        switch (cTypeCode) {
            case 1:
                cType = "INBOX";
                break;
            case 2:
                cType = "SENT";
                break;
            case 3:
                cType = "DRAFT";
                break;
        }
        if (sdate.contains(syear)) {
            if (sdate.contains(smonth)) {
                if (cType.contains("SENT")) {
                    olnum.add(phoneNumber);
                    oltype.add(cType);
                    oldate.add(smsDateTime);
                    countout++;
                } else if (cType.contains("INBOX")) {
                    ilnum.add(phoneNumber);
                    iltype.add(cType);
                    ildate.add(smsDateTime);
                    countin++;
                } else if (cType.contains("DRAFT")) {
                    dlnum.add(phoneNumber);
                    dltype.add(cType);
                    dldate.add(smsDateTime);
                    countdel++;
                }
            }
        }
    }
    managedCursor.close();
    tv_countout.setText(new StringBuilder().append(formateTime(countout)));
    tv_countin.setText(new StringBuilder().append(formateTime(countin)));
    tv_countdel.setText(new StringBuilder().append(formateTime(countdel)));
}
```

Comment: what is the value of cTypeCode ?

Comment: the values in all test are 1,2 and 3 i get the crash by cType.contains("SENT") and in the debugger stands as value SENT or INBOX or DRAFT

Comment: Log.d cTypeCode and see the values

Comment: Sorry for the long wait, i had a lot of trouble in the last days. The log says 0, but why? What me in this situation confused that on the Emulator with Lollipop comes no crashes but on the N5 it come the crash.

Comment: see https://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/Telephony.TextBasedSmsColumns.html look at MESSAGE_TYPE_*